# Pandas. Удаление записей о повторных ошибках из dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Привет всем!

Имеется dataframe типа:

| SrvName | Started | Status | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| server1 | 2023-06-01 14:00:00 | sucsess | 10000 |
| server2 | 2023-06-01 14:05:00 | sucsess | 12000 |
| server3 | 2023-06-01 14:25:00 | sucsess | 20000 |
| server1 | 2023-06-02 14:00:00 | failed | 0 |
| server2 | 2023-06-01 14:05:00 | sucsess | 1000 |
| **server1** | **2023-06-02 14:10:00** | **failed** | **0** |
| **server1** | **2023-06-02 14:20:00** | **failed** | **0** |
| server3 | 2023-06-02 14:25:00 | sucsess | 20000 |
| **server1** | **2023-06-02 14:25:00** | **failed** | **0** |
| **server1** | **2023-06-02 14:30:00** | **failed** | **0** |

итд.
Нужно дропнуть записи со значением failed в столбце **Status** которые возникли в течении 30 минут, после первого failed в разрезе **SrvName** (выделил **болдом**). В итоге должна остаться одна запись failed на сервер в диапазоне 30 минут от возникновения первого failed.

**Update**: События Started не обязательно могут быть кратным 5 минутам.
Решил вот так:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
['server1','2023-06-01 14:00:00','sucsess',10000],
['server2','2023-06-01 14:05:00','sucsess',12000],
['server3','2023-06-01 14:25:00','sucsess',20000],
['server1','2023-06-02 14:00:00','failed',0],
['server2','2023-06-01 14:05:00','sucsess',1000],
['server1','2023-06-02 14:10:00','failed',0],
['server1','2023-06-02 14:20:00','failed',0],
['server3','2023-06-02 14:25:00','sucsess',20000],
['server1','2023-06-02 14:25:00','failed',0],
['server1','2023-06-02 14:30:00','failed',0],
['server2','2023-07-02 14:30:00','failed',0]],
columns=['SrvName','Started','Status','Size'])
df['Started']=pd.to_datetime(df.Started)

df_temp=df.loc[df['Status']=='failed'].groupby(['SrvName'])['Started'].diff(periods=1).fillna(pd.Timedelta('01:30:00'))
df_temp2=df_temp[df_temp>pd.Timedelta('00:30:00')]
df_filtered = df.loc[(df.Status == 'sucsess') | df.index.isin(df_temp2.index)]
```

ИМХО несколько корявенько выглядит решение. Хотя бы тем, что я присваиваю первым событиям со статусом failed timedelta равное полутора часам, ну что бы априори было больше 30 минут. Кроме того, в этом решении фильтруются события со статусом failed произошедшие в течении 30 минут от **предыдущего** события, а не от того, что было первым. **Вот это пока не смог победить**.

Спасибо камрадам, что натолкнули на правильные мысли!

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите ваши попытки решения.

Answer (score 1):

Я взял побольше датафрейм, чтобы было на чем тестить.

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['SrvNam',    'Started',  'Status',   'Size']
data = [['server1', '2023-06-01 14:00:00',  'sucsess',  '10000'],
['server2', '2023-06-01 14:05:00',  'sucsess',  12000],
['server3', '2023-06-01 14:25:00',  'sucsess',  20000],
['server1', '2023-06-02 14:00:00',  'failed',   0],
['server2', '2023-06-01 14:05:00',  'sucsess',  1000],
['server1', '2023-06-02 14:10:00',  'failed',   0],
['server1', '2023-06-02 14:20:00',  'failed',   0],
['server3', '2023-06-02 14:25:00',  'sucsess',  20000],
['server3', '2023-06-02 14:26:00',  'failed',   0],
['server2', '2023-06-02 14:30:00',  'failed',   0],
['server2', '2023-06-02 14:35:00',  'failed',   0],
['server3', '2023-06-02 14:28:00',  'failed',   0],
['server1', '2023-06-02 14:30:00',  'failed',   0],
['server2', '2023-06-02 15:01:00',  'failed',   0],
['server2', '2023-06-02 15:01:00',  'failed',   0],
['server3', '2023-06-02 15:30:00',  'failed',   0],
['server3', '2023-06-02 15:40:00',  'failed',   0]
]


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Дальше, если у Вас колонка с датой/временем в формате `datetime` - работаем дальше, если в формате `str` переводим в `datetime`.

```
df.Started = pd.to_datetime(df.Started)
```

Далее так:

1. Фильтруем столбец 'Status' по значению 'failed'
2. Добавляем колонку с индексами внутрь датафрейма
3. Группируем по именам серверов
4. Внутри групп делаем ресемплирование по колонке даты/времени на блоки по 30 мин.
5. Берем индекс минимального элемента в каждой группе

```
df_g = df[df.Status == 'failed'].reset_index().groupby('SrvNam').resample('30T', on='Started', origin='start').min()['index']
```

В результате мы получаем серию индексов первых элементов в каждой группе серверов, разбитых на отрезки по 30 мин.

Последним шагом применяем фильтрацию к исходному датафрейму с двумя условиями:

1. Или статус == 'sucsess'
2. Или берем индексы из полученного списка

```
df_filtered = df.loc[(df.Status == 'sucsess') | df.index.isin(df_g)]
```

Comment: вообще, 30 минут для группера записать можно как "30T", а не "1800s". Ну и самое главное, ресамплинг работает по отрезкам выравненным по началу часа. а в вопросе речь идет о разнице между первым событием и последующими. при этом не говорится, что время первого события может быть кратно 30 минутам.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Действительно, кратности никакой нет. Одно событие может произойти в 14:59, а второе в 15:03.   Я пытался делать так:
`df.loc[df['Status']=='failed'].groupby(['SrvNam'])['Started'].diff(periods=1)`
и затем сравнивать получившуюся серию с `pd.Timedelta('00:30:00')`. и вот что-то не получается всё это вместе увязать :-(

Comment: @strawdog Согласен с обоими замечаниями, решается добавлением в resample параметра 'origin = "start"'. Исправил в ответе.

Comment: @Лацитус Я исправил свой ответ. Теперь каждый 30-минутный интервал начинается не кратно получасу, а со времени первой ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Решение с помощью машины состояний. Создается функция - генератор, в которую поступают строки фрейма по очереди. Для отслеживания времени сбоев в разрезе серверов создан словарь lastf, в который пишется ключ "имя сервера" и значение - последний актуальный сбой. Если поступает новое время сбоя по тому же серверу с разницей более 180 секунд, информация обновляется на новое время. Далее реализована логика, которая на выходе возвращает резюме для каждой строки на удаление - истину или ложь.

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['SrvNam', 'Started', 'Status', 'Size']
data = [['server1', '2023-06-01 14:00:00', 'sucsess', '10000'],
        ['server2', '2023-06-01 14:05:00', 'sucsess', 12000],
        ['server3', '2023-06-01 14:25:00', 'sucsess', 20000],
        ['server1', '2023-06-02 14:00:00', 'failed', 0],
        ['server2', '2023-06-01 14:05:00', 'sucsess', 1000],
        ['server1', '2023-06-02 14:10:00', 'failed', 0],
        ['server1', '2023-06-02 14:20:00', 'failed', 0],
        ['server3', '2023-06-02 14:25:00', 'sucsess', 20000],
        ['server3', '2023-06-02 14:26:00', 'failed', 0],
        ['server2', '2023-06-02 14:30:00', 'failed', 0],
        ['server2', '2023-06-02 14:35:00', 'failed', 0],
        ['server3', '2023-06-02 14:28:00', 'failed', 0],
        ['server1', '2023-06-02 14:30:00', 'failed', 0],
        ['server1', '2023-06-02 14:30:01', 'failed', 0],
        ['server2', '2023-06-02 15:01:00', 'failed', 0],
        ['server2', '2023-06-02 15:01:00', 'failed', 0],
        ['server1', '2023-06-02 14:45:01', 'failed', 0],
        ['server3', '2023-06-02 15:30:00', 'failed', 0],
        ['server1', '2023-06-02 15:40:00', 'failed', 0]
        ]


def state_machine():
    srv, started, status = yield
    lastf = {}
    tdelta = pd.Timedelta(30, 'm')
    while True:
        delete = False
        if status == 'failed' and lastf.get(srv):
            if started - lastf[srv] > tdelta:
                lastf[srv] = started
            else:
                delete = True
        elif status == 'failed' and lastf.get(srv) is None:
            lastf[srv] = started

        srv, started, status = yield delete


machine = state_machine()
next(machine)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.Started = pd.to_datetime(df.Started, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df['К удалению'] = df.apply(lambda x: machine.send((x['SrvNam'], x['Started'], x['Status'])), axis=1)
print(df[df.SrvNam.eq('server1')])

df = df[df['К удалению'].eq(False)].drop(columns=['К удалению'])  # далее можно отфильтровать ненужные строки и удалив вспомогательный столбец
print(df)
```

**Промежуточный отладочный вывод по серверу 1**

```
     SrvNam             Started   Status   Size  К удалению
0   server1 2023-06-01 14:00:00  sucsess  10000       False
3   server1 2023-06-02 14:00:00   failed      0       False
5   server1 2023-06-02 14:10:00   failed      0        True
6   server1 2023-06-02 14:20:00   failed      0        True
12  server1 2023-06-02 14:30:00   failed      0        True
13  server1 2023-06-02 14:30:01   failed      0       False
16  server1 2023-06-02 14:45:01   failed      0        True
18  server1 2023-06-02 15:40:00   failed      0       False
```

**Итоговый вывод**

```
     SrvNam             Started   Status   Size
0   server1 2023-06-01 14:00:00  sucsess  10000
1   server2 2023-06-01 14:05:00  sucsess  12000
2   server3 2023-06-01 14:25:00  sucsess  20000
3   server1 2023-06-02 14:00:00   failed      0
4   server2 2023-06-01 14:05:00  sucsess   1000
7   server3 2023-06-02 14:25:00  sucsess  20000
8   server3 2023-06-02 14:26:00   failed      0
9   server2 2023-06-02 14:30:00   failed      0
13  server1 2023-06-02 14:30:01   failed      0
14  server2 2023-06-02 15:01:00   failed      0
17  server3 2023-06-02 15:30:00   failed      0
18  server1 2023-06-02 15:40:00   failed      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так:

```py
df_temp=df.loc[df['Status']=='failed'].groupby(['SrvNam'])['Started'].diff(periods=1).fillna(pd.Timedelta('01:30:00'))
df_temp2=df_temp[df_temp>pd.Timedelta('00:30:00')]
df_filtered = df.loc[(df.Status == 'sucsess') | df.index.isin(df_temp2.index)]
```

ИМХО несколько корявенько выглядит решение. Хотя бы тем, что я присваиваю первым событиям со статусом failed timedelta равное полутора часам, ну что бы априори было больше 30 минут.
Кроме того, в этом решении фильтруются события со статусом failed произошедшие в течении 30 минут от **предыдущего** события, а не от того, что было первым. **Вот это пока не смог победить**.

Comment: Вы бы лучше свое решение в вопрос добавили. Так-то у вас вопрос без вашего кода не соответствует требованиям сайта, а ответ, как вы сами написали, не такой уж и "ответ".

Answer (score 0):

я бы сделал проще:

Исходный df:

```
    SrvName             Started   Status   Size
0   server1 2023-06-01 14:11:11  sucsess  10000
1   server2 2023-06-01 14:05:00  sucsess  12000
2   server3 2023-06-01 14:25:00  sucsess  20000
3   server1 2023-06-02 14:11:00   failed      0
4   server2 2023-06-01 14:15:00  sucsess   1000
5   server1 2023-06-02 14:22:00   failed      0
6   server1 2023-06-02 14:27:00   failed      0
7   server3 2023-06-02 14:25:00  sucsess  20000
8   server1 2023-06-02 14:31:00   failed      0
9   server1 2023-06-02 14:33:00   failed      0
10  server1 2023-06-02 14:35:00   failed      0
11  server1 2023-06-02 14:45:00   failed      0
12  server1 2023-06-02 15:47:00   failed      0
13  server1 2023-06-02 15:52:00   failed      0
14  server1 2023-06-02 16:02:00   failed      0
```

решение:

```python
# группируем по серверам и статусу:
for _, g in df[df["Status"]=="failed"].groupby("SrvName"):
# получаем диффы во времени, кратные 30 минутам от первого времени
    g["diff"] = (g["Started"].diff().cumsum()//pd.Timedelta(30, "min")).fillna(method="bfill")
# группируем по этим диффам, получаем индексы всех рядов, кроме первого
    for _, t in g.groupby("diff"):
        idx = t.iloc[1:].index
# удаляем эти ряды из исходного датафрейма
        df = df.drop(index=idx)
```

теперь df:

```
    SrvName             Started   Status   Size
0   server1 2023-06-01 14:11:11  sucsess  10000
1   server2 2023-06-01 14:05:00  sucsess  12000
2   server3 2023-06-01 14:25:00  sucsess  20000
3   server1 2023-06-02 14:11:00   failed      0
4   server2 2023-06-01 14:15:00  sucsess   1000
7   server3 2023-06-02 14:25:00  sucsess  20000
11  server1 2023-06-02 14:45:00   failed      0
12  server1 2023-06-02 15:47:00   failed      0
```